# Is webmail also use POP/IMAP Protocol to retrieve email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, pop3

I have seen many sites and I knew about POP/IMAP protocol. I knew that email clients such as : outlook, etc will use one of those protocol from mail server. But if I use webmail, it means that I access the mail server directly without email client software. So, is webmail still use the (POP or IMAP protocol) or not?

Comment: 'webmail' is a description of how you access it, not the underlying protocol. Many services can be accessed by web, IMAP and POP.

Comment: So, if I access my gmail account in my borwser it means that I am not using either IMAP or POP?

Comment: You're using https, same as any other web page

Comment: Ok... I got it Now. Thanks a lot  :)